# Best way to do an Anti-join in RedShift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

An anti-join is a way of getting tuples in one table that don't match in another table.

There are numerous ways we can implement an anti-join:

- Correlated sub-query
- Uncorrelated Sub-query
- Outer Join and Check for NULL

Which is the most optimal way to perform an anti-join in Redshift? The correlated sub-query in this case, is not optimial and the RedShift's query engine does not decorrelate that query.

Comment: why don't you try them and compare the times? i think as a general rule outer joins are pretty much always better than subqueries in any DB

Comment: I don't actually have a RedShift instance. I'm just working on theoretical aspects.

Comment: It makes sense that the joins would be faster if we set the dist key and sort key appropriately. Anti-joins seem so common but RedShift explicitly mentions it doesn't support the correlated `DOES NOT EXIST` subquery.

Answer (score 7):

As @denismo said, it's hard without context, but you can try something like:

```
SELECT ...
FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b USING(key)
WHERE b.key is null
```

it will return the list of rows in a that their key does not exist in a

Comment: But be aware that this won't be null-safe! Meaning that if any value is NULL it won't be filtered out!

Answer (score 3):

Without actual table layout and statistics, and actual query, it's hard to give definitive answer to this.

I could speculate that this kind of task, would require a HashJoin on Redshift side. If one of the tables is not too large, and both have the same dist keys, it can be done efficiently in memory. Outer Join with Null check then sounds the most suitable as it is the most predictable - it'll do just that.

But the actual performance will depend on many factors, better come back once you have tables/query.